# Autogenerate link title based on URL/target for accessibility

Tags: typo3, accessibility, typo3-11.x

I would like to automatically add the respective addition: “opens external link” on external URLs using `target="_blank"` or “opens email program” to email links that exist in a text, for example, as link title. I think that would have existed in TYPO3 before. I think that's beneficial for accessibility, right? Can someone help me there?

Comment: Please also specify your TYPO3 version.

Comment: it is TYPO3 11.5.36